# How to control amount of decimals after the decimal point?

Tags: php

This is my entity:

```
 /**
  * @var decimal
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="measure", type="decimal", scale=3)
  */

  private $measure;
```

I want to calculate different measures like:

```
$entity->measure = 0.250-0.500;
```

My problem is that my input of `0.250` is stored as `0.25`.

I wonder how to make it keep the three digits after the decimal point regardless if they are zero.

Comment: Your question was not tagged the best way as this is pretty much php-only. Also, when wording a question try to keep it concise. It did not matter for your use case that you are calculating the amount of fluids in a certain way, you have a value and want it to appear a certain way. I have rephrased your question in an edit.

Comment: Sorry but i am from argentina, and i dont speak very well.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. =) Everybody has to start somewhere.

Comment: i do a query that provide me, the measures and the prices of a product.
I keep that result in $measuresandprices. How I can access the prices? Like this? : $measuresandprices['prices'][$i] and go iterating $i ???

Comment: Comments are not for follow up question. Please open a new question, though I advise you to search use cases on how to access arrays, or ArrayCollections returned by doctrine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep storing it as a float, you don't need the zero in the database.

In order to format the number when outputting use: [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php).

```
<?php
echo number_format(.25,3); // outputs "0.250", depending on your locale may output "0,250"
```

When you store a value, its representation should not determine the way it is stored.

Comment: You can also use printf("%.3f",  $my_number);